# core text - CTRunGetGlyphs is garbage - iOS

Tags: ios, core-text

This code here seems to mostly work -- I can print out each run and it looks like the runs are valid but when I print out the glyphs they are garbage.  Also the positions are all at (0,0) and I the bounds don't look right to me.  Can someone help me maybe I'm not doing these things correctly, this is by the way just an example program so I can take a look at the actual data within the runs.

```
-(void) printRuns:(CTFrameRef)ctframe {
    CFArrayRef lines;
    lines = CTFrameGetLines(ctframe);

    CGPoint origins[CFArrayGetCount(lines)];//the origins of each line at the baseline
    CTFrameGetLineOrigins(ctframe, CFRangeMake(0, 0), origins);

    NSUInteger lineIndex = 0;

    for(int i = 0; i < CFArrayGetCount(lines); i++)
    //for(id lineObj in lines)
    {
        CTLineRef line = CFArrayGetValueAtIndex(lines, i);

        NSLog(@"LineOrigin:%@", NSStringFromCGPoint(origins[i]));

        CFArrayRef runs = CTLineGetGlyphRuns(line);

        for(int j = 0; j < CFArrayGetCount(runs); j++)
        //for(id runObj in (__bridge NSArray*)CTLineGetGlyphRuns(line))
        {
            CTRunRef run = CFArrayGetValueAtIndex(runs, j);
            CFRange runRange = CTRunGetStringRange(run);


            CGRect runBounds;

            CGFloat ascent;//height above the baseline
            CGFloat descent;//height below the baseline
            runBounds.size.width = CTRunGetTypographicBounds(run, runRange, &ascent, &descent, NULL);
            runBounds.size.height = ascent + descent;

            CGFloat xOffset = CTLineGetOffsetForStringIndex(line, CTRunGetStringRange(run).location, NULL);
            runBounds.origin.x = origins[lineIndex].x + 0 + xOffset;
            runBounds.origin.y = origins[lineIndex].y + 0;
            runBounds.origin.y -= descent;

            CGGlyph glyphBuffer[runRange.length];

            CTRunGetGlyphs(run, runRange, glyphBuffer);

            //const CGGlyph *glyphs = CTRunGetGlyphsPtr(run);
            //NSLog(@"Glyph:%c", glyph);

            for(int i = 0; i < runRange.length; i++)
            {
                NSLog(@"Glyph:%c", glyphBuffer[i]);

                if(i % 10 == 0)
                {
                    NSString *test = @"";
                }
            }

            CFIndex glyphCount = CTRunGetGlyphCount(run);
            CGPoint *positions = calloc(glyphCount, sizeof(CGPoint));
            CTRunGetPositions(run, runRange, positions);

            for(int i = 0; i < glyphCount; i++)
            {
                CGPoint *position = &positions[i];
                NSLog(@"Position:%@", NSStringFromCGPoint(*position));
            }


            NSLog(@"%@", NSStringFromCGRect(runBounds));
        }
        lineIndex++;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The most likely problem is that the font from which you're pulling the glyphs and the one in which your trying to display them is different.  If so this would explain the 'garbage' glyphs since a glyph in one font can represent a different letter from the same glyph in another (a CGGlyph is just an index into a font's individual table of glyphs and different fonts can lay out character sets their glyphs differently).  This would also explain the bounding box mismatches.

As for the positioning, did you try using CTFontGetAdvancesForGlyphs instead?  I suspect that the positions data only represents the position of the bounding box for the current glyph relative to the current placement of the 'cursor,' not relative to the start of the run.

Finally, the sample code above assumes that one character maps to one glyph.  This is not true in general.  English sometimes is typeset with ligatures (in which two or more characters are represented by one glyph) but many languages have ligatures all over the place.  You need to use CTRunGetGlyphCount().